# Is it possible to Show Hide a button on a Webpage when a User's Javascript is turned off?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-webpages

Is it possible to Show Hide a button on a Webpage when a User's Javascript is turned off?

I need to show or Hide a Button element on my webpage depending on whether or not the User turns on his Javascript ON.

I know I can show content when JS is disabled using the `<noscript>` tag, but how could I enable/disable a button when JS is disabled. I'm basically working on an expand/collapse kind of button scenario where clicking the button would expand/collapse the content.

Are there any possibilities of achieving this?

Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: You can have the button initially hidden then use js to show it. Therefore the button is hidden if js is turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initially hide your button and then display it with javascript right away onload. e.g.

```
<button id="btn" style="display: none;">JS Button</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('btn').style.display = "block";
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a link or a button set like this :

```
<div id="buttonContent" style="display:none">
  Button/Link content goes here.
</div>
```

Then, we show the  with Javascript :

```
<script type=text/javascript>
window.onload = function ()
{
 document.getElementById('buttonContent').style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

That way, if the user's javascript is disable, the windows doesn't show, if you want the opposite, just start showing it and then hidde it with JS.